# Problema ao enviar imagem para banco de dados

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server

Possuo uma aplicação web no qual o usuário pode alterar sua imagem de perfil, estou conseguindo selecionar o arquivo de imagem corretamente, o problema esta na hora de enviar para o banco (envio os dados da aplicação para um webService e do websService para o banco de dados), que me retorna erro 400.

HTML:

```
<div id="userImage">
   <image id="profileImage" src="" />
   <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
</div>
```

JavaScript (Enviando para o webService):

```
function UpdateImage(email){
    var img1 = document.getElementById('profileImage').src;
    var body = JSON.stringify({ "UserName": email, "UserImage": img1 });
    console.log(img1);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'minha rota',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        type: 'Post',
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: body,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Método do webService que preenche o banco de dados (C#):

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("minha rota")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostImage(IdUser user)
        {  
            try
            {
                byte[] images = null;
                FileStream Streem = new FileStream(user.UserImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(Streem);
                images = brs.ReadBytes((int)Streem.Length);

                bool result = false;

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandText = "insert into IdUser (UserImage) values (@images) where UserName = @username";

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("images", images);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", user.UserName);

                        int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        result = i > 0;
                    }

                    connection.Close();
                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

O erro ocorre na linha `FileStream Streem = new FileStream(user.UserImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` retornando o erro 400 :

> O caminho especificado, o nome do arquivo ou ambos são muito longos. O
>   nome de arquivo totalmente qualificado deve ter menos de 260
>   caracteres e o nome do diretório menos de 248 caracteres.

O valor que esta chegando no webService é uma rota do tipo base64 com tamanho de 7000 caracteres, que é obviamente a causa do erro. O problema é que aparentemente uma rota do tipo base64 não pode ser reduzida. Já passei alguns dias pesquisando, gostaria de saber como resolver este problema.

Comment: o primeiro parâmetro ali é um caminho para o arquivo ex : "c:\teste.jpg", você está tentando colocar um base64, por isso o erro

Comment: @Lucas Miranda A qual parâmetro esta se referindo ? "FileMode.Open" ?

Comment: esse user.UserImage, imagino que seja onde está seu base64

Comment: @Lucas Miranda Correto, mas este campo (UserImage) é uma string.

Comment: sim, mas é pra ser uma string contendo o caminho do arquivo, não um base64, o seu erro ocorre porque no geral um caminho não tem a enorme quantidade de caracteres que um base64 possui

Comment: @Lucas Miranda Existe alguma forma de converter o base64 para uma rota do tipo "c:\teste.jpg" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe que você está tentando converter seu base64 em uma stream para então convertê-lo em bytes

```
byte[] images = null;
FileStream Streem = new FileStream(user.UserImage, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(Streem);
images = brs.ReadBytes((int)Streem.Length);
```

Acredito que você não precise fazer isso, pois é possível transformar um base64 diretamente em bytes usando o `Convert`, ficaria assim:

```
byte[] images = null;                     
images = System.Convert.FromBase64String(user.UserImage);
```